# Admob crashing the app

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play, admob

I tried running my code without admob first. It works fine. Then I tried running my code with the admob the app just crashes on start doesn't even show a message just crashes. 
I have provided the code for activity main and layout.xml and manifest. If you need to look at the imageAdapter and GalleryFlow I will post that too.
Here is my code:

```
   public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
   private GalleryFlow mGalleryFlow;
   private AdView adView;
   private InterstitialAd interstitial;

      private int[] imageIds = new int[] { R.drawable.gal1, R.drawable.gal2,
            R.drawable.gal3, R.drawable.gal4, R.drawable.gal5,
            R.drawable.gal6, R.drawable.gal7, R.drawable.gal8,
            R.drawable.gal9, R.drawable.gal10, R.drawable.gal11,
            R.drawable.gal12, R.drawable.gal13, R.drawable.gal14,
            R.drawable.gal15, R.drawable.gal16, R.drawable.gal17,};
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_gallery);

    findViews();
     initViews();
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY ID HERE");


     RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutAdView);
     layout.addView(adView);


     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();


    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("MY ID HERE");

      AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
    }






    private void findViews() {
        mGalleryFlow = (GalleryFlow) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageIds);

        adapter.createReflectedImages();
        mGalleryFlow.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Layout xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Runhere"
  android:background="#FFA500" >


 <com.norka.gallery.GalleryFlow 
 android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/layoutAdView"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.norka.gallery"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />



     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
      <activity android:name="com.norka.gallery.ActivityMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
       </activity>

   </application>


</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
09-15 07:32:38.798: I/MultiDex(30217): install
09-15 07:32:38.798: I/MultiDex(30217): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/downloads/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, false)
09-15 07:32:38.808: I/MultiDex(30217): loading existing secondary dex files
09-15 07:32:38.808: I/MultiDex(30217): load found 1 secondary dex files
09-15 07:32:38.808: I/MultiDex(30217): install done
09-15 07:32:38.808: I/ProviderInstaller(30217): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
09-15 07:32:38.828: I/MultiDex(30234): install
09-15 07:32:38.828: I/MultiDex(30234): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/downloads/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, false)
09-15 07:32:38.838: D/PackageBroadcastService(30217): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.norka.gallery
09-15 07:32:38.838: D/dalvikvm(30217): Trying to load lib /data/downloads/libAppDataSearch.so 0x95fb0a40
09-15 07:32:38.838: E/dalvikvm(30217): dlopen("/data/downloads/libAppDataSearch.so") failed: dlopen failed: "/data/downloads/libAppDataSearch.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
09-15 07:32:38.838: E/Icing(30217): Native load error: dlopen failed: "/data/downloads/libAppDataSearch.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
09-15 07:32:38.838: I/MultiDex(30234): loading existing secondary dex files
09-15 07:32:38.838: I/MultiDex(30234): load found 1 secondary dex files
09-15 07:32:38.838: I/MultiDex(30234): install done
09-15 07:32:38.848: I/Icing(30217): Storage manager: low false usage 9.34KB avail 6.17GB capacity 6.59GB
09-15 07:32:38.858: I/ProviderInstaller(30234): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
09-15 07:32:38.868: D/dalvikvm(30217): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 430K, 21% free 2955K/3728K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
09-15 07:32:38.938: E/Icing(30217): Error initializing, resetting corpora: Could not create native index
09-15 07:32:38.938: E/Icing(30217): Internal init failed
09-15 07:32:38.938: E/Icing(30217): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED intent due to initialization failure.
09-15 07:32:39.108: D/PackageBroadcastService(30217): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.norka.gallery
09-15 07:32:39.178: E/Icing(30217): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent due to initialization failure.
09-15 07:32:39.218: I/PeopleContactsSync(30217): CP2 sync disabled
09-15 07:32:39.318: D/dalvikvm(30217): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 590K, 17% free 3189K/3812K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
09-15 07:32:39.758: D/PackageBroadcastService(30217): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.norka.gallery
09-15 07:32:39.758: E/Icing(30217): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED intent due to initialization failure.
```

09-15 07:32:39.758: I/PeopleContactsSync(30217): CP2 sync disabled

Comment: post your full error  logcat

Comment: This is the full LogCat error ...

Comment: This does not look like an Admob error. You are getting a fault loading native packages. I presume these are local to your app.

Answer (score -1):

You would be much better off declaring your adView in your XML code. It will prevent weird stuff such as you are seeing from happening. Here's an example of how to declare it in XML.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical" style="@style/background">

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" 
     ads:adSize="BANNER" 
     ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </com.google.ads.AdView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I believe the preferred way is to set the id and size programmatically actually, though it is not depreciated.

Comment: this refers to legacy admob, but the question was about the new [google play version of admob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration#create-adview)